# Should/Can one upvote oneself?

Tags: support, etiquette

The answer to the first part (Should) is obviously, "No!", but I'm reluctant to test the possibility for that very reason.

Comment: Just go ahead and try upvoting this very question of yours.

Comment: Thanks -- brill.  (But superstitiously, I'll trust you rather than pressing the button!)  I upvoted (and Accepted) your answer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't vote (up/down) for your own post.

[image: You can't vote for your own post.]

But you still can vote to close, reopen or (un)delete your own posts.